# Is there a way to get max using pandas Dataframe.eval instead of Dataframe.max?

Tags: pandas

Is there a way to get the maximum per row using `eval`?

It would be very sweet to be able to write something like:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4]})
X.eval("""B = 2* A
          C = A +B
          D = max(A, B)
          E = 2 * D
          """, inplace = True)
```

Instead of:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4]})
X.eval("""B = 2* A
          C = A +B
          """, inplace = True)

X['D'] = X.loc[:,['A', 'B']].max(axis=1)

X.eval('E = 2 * D', inplace=True)
```

EDIT:
As suggested by @mephisto, something similar to this works beautifully:

```
def rowmax(A,B):
   return pd.concat([A,B], axis=1).max(axis=1)

X = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0, 1,2,3,4]})
X.eval("""B = A % 2 +1
          D = @rowmax(A, B)
       """, inplace = True)
```

I am interested in knowing other alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure how `if-else` solutions work with eval, would be interesting to know.

Comment: Are you just interested only by the max or you look for a solution that can be used for different functions?

Comment: max and min mostly, but also something that can be also used in query calls.

Comment: @ManuelCastejónLimas because you can see max of two columns as checking A<B and then multiply the result with B and the opposite of this result by A and sum both, try: `X.eval("""D = A<B\nD = ~D*A + D*B""", inplace = True)`. This way may not be possible for any kind of function you want to apply

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call a custom or predefined function with `@`. In your case you want to call `df.max()`, so try this `X.eval('@df.max()')`. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Good solution. I will add sth in that line to the question. I'm interested in knowing if a built-in solution is available.